# Python 3.6 TypeError: string indices must be integers when trying to send office 365 email

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, outlook, typeerror

Trying to automate some emails I send out every morning. Having some issues when including multiple attachments and can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

```
from O365 import Message, Attachment
import getpass

email_list = {
    'email1': {
        'recipients': 'adiosz@outlook.com',
        'subject': 'test subject',
        'body': 'test body',
        'files': ["file1.xlsx", "file2.xlsx"]
    }
    'email2': {
        'recipients': 'adiosz@outlook.com',
        'subject': 'test subject',
        'body': 'test body',
        'files': ["file3.xlsx", "file4.xlsx"]
    }
}

username = input('Enter your email: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Enter your password: ')
o365_auth = (username, password)


def daily_email(recipients, subject, body, files):
    m = Message(auth=o365_auth)
    m.setRecipients(recipients)
    m.setSubject(subject)
    m.setBody(body)
    for file in files:
        att = Attachment(file)
        m.attachments.append(att)
    m.sendMessage()


for email, email_contents in email_list.items():
    daily_email(email_contents['recipients'], email_contents['subject'], email_contents['body'], email_contents['files'])
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\emails2.py", line 46, in <module>
    email_contents['files'])
  File ".\emails2.py", line 34, in daily_emails
    att = Attachment(file)
  File "C:\Users\adiosz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\O365\attachment.py", line 50,
 in __init__
    self.isPDF = '.pdf' in self.json['Name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Thank you!

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables to see what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the filename to add as attachment is supposed to be in the second parameter. See :

https://github.com/Narcolapser/python-o365/blob/master/O365/attachment.py#L35

So change the line `att = Attachment(file)` with `att = Attachment(path=file)` and it should work.

BTW, do not use the `file` variable name, you are overriding a builtin type.